# Search value in column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Im tring to search string in column sql.
I want to search if   (the first 3 caracters of the column =='DOC' and the first word after **/** is 'FILE1') or the value ends with **TMP**.

```
case 
when desc like '%TMP' OR (SUBSTRING(desc, 1, 3) =='DOC') then 'F1'
else 'Not found'
end as 't1'
```

[image: Description]

Comment: You have removed the postgresql tag - has that been intentional? If it was, please specify the database system you are using, as the syntactic validity of the answer will depend on that.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use the postgresql regex match operator `~` (relevant section of Postgresql 12 docs: [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#id-1.5.8.12.9.2)):

```
select "desc"
     , case 
           when "desc" like '%TMP' OR "desc" ~ '^DOC[^/]*/FILE1/'
           then 'F1'
           else 'Not found'
       end as t1
  from (
           select 'DOCument123/FILE1/' "desc"
        union all
           select 'DOCument123/FILE1/' "desc"
        union all
           select 'DOCument123/FILE1/' "desc"
        union all
           select 'TDZVDLS' "desc"
        union all
           select 'TDZVDLSTMP' "desc"
      ) x;
```

Includes 2 syntax corrections:

- `desc` is a reserved sql identifier and needs wrapping in double quotes to be used as a column alias.
- The alis `t1` is a column name and is written without the enclosing single quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your response  its useful. i can do directly from tablename without passing 'union'?

Comment: sure. My `from` clause is written to allow standalone execution of the statement, just replace it with your table name.

Comment: thank you and and if i understand well the ~ similar to like . didn't understand this part please . **[^/]*/**

Comment: `~` denotes regular expression matching. Regular expressions ( short: regex ) are a formal pattern matching language. For an intro, see [here](regular-expression.info). In this language, `[^/]*` means 'match any number of characters different from `/`, possibly none at all'. Relevant section of Postgresql 12 docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#id-1.5.8.12.9.2)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with `like`:

```
select (case when col like 'DOC%/FILE1%' then 'F1' else 'Not Found' end)
```

This is all standard SQL, so it should work on any database.